# UISearchBar's edit animation gone in iOS8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, ios8

I am implementing a custom search on a table for iOS. I noticed that the slide animation became a little jumpy for iOS 8, where it was smooth in iOS 7. Did anyone notice the same problem and got a fix for it?

Here's two gifs showing exactly what I mean:

This is iOS 7:

[image: UISearchBar edit animation in iOS 7]

This is the same search bar in iOS 8:

[image: UISearchBar edit animation in iOS 8]

Notice how the search icon and "Search" string jumps about 100 points to the left/right, then slide to its final position in iOS 8, while it is a linear interpolation in iOS 7.

Comment: Gif has less frame rate. Check it out yourself in xcode :L

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I've found that this seems to be caused by `setShowsCancelButton:animated:` method. Removing it fixed animation.

Instead of putting the above method in `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:`, put it in `searchBarDidBeginEditing`.

To dismiss, put the above method in `searchBarShouldEndEditing:` instead of `searchBarDidEndEditing`.